# AngularJS not loading in plunker

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, menu

My plunker is not loading the AngularJS. I started this page using Editey from my GoogleDrive and runs ok there. I moved it to plunker using the same directory structure but it does not load Angular. Any help? 
This is my plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/dEY7ag/

Comment: you should definitely check console. there are some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your plunker is, where as your Filename is `Factory.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/Factories.js"></script>
```

That is the reason you are getting the below injection error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=MenuFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20MenuFactory%20%3C-%20NavigationController
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:121
    at Object.d [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:195
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:362)
    at M.instance (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:80:336)
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:61:362)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105)
```

Comment: Thank you Thalaivar, it worked with that fixed. Thank you @Denis